Sorting a View In hook_views_pre_render failing in final display
Note: I am editing this highly from its initial post to focus on the oddity I've noticed. The point is slightly moot, as I was able to achieve my goal with ViewsSort Plugin; however, I can easily imagine a complex computation that would be far easier to do in PHP after the results are retrieved than with a database query.
This is a Drupal 10 site, and all references I can find to similar issues are greatly outdated.
I attempted to sort a Views result according to some custom math with a usort inside hook_views_pre_render:
function hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view){
  if($view->id() === 'my_id' && $view->current_display === 'my_display') {
    /** @var \Drupal\views\ResultRow $a */
    /** @var \Drupal\views\ResultRow $b */
    usort($view->result, function($a, $b){
      // Extract values from the $a & $b rows, do a bunch of math for the final comparison of row values.
      return ($row1_value <=> $row2_value);
    });

The details of the sort are inconsequential. What's important is the following information I've gathered from judiciously placed logging statements and/or xdebug breakpoints:

The usort is entered, the expected sums are correctly calculated.
Immediately after the usort, an examination of $view->result shows the order has been modified, and is correct.
Inside a hook_views_post_render, inspection of the ViewExecutable shows the order is still correct.
In \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable::render(), inspection of the ViewExecutable shows the order is still correct.
In \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\style\StylePluginBase::render(), inspection of the ViewExecutable shows the order is still correct.
All looks good everywhere I check, but the final display on the page is not properly sorted. I.e., it doesn't match the order of any of the above inspections.
It’s not the same order as before/without the usort, but it’s not correct either.
The ordering has nothing to do with anything I’ve been able to deduce, but it is consistent.
If I add some kind of sort through the UI (e.g., title, created on), I get altered final ordering, but they match neither my usort nor the ordering specified by the UI.

I'd like to find out how/why/where the specified order I created is getting messed up and to overcome it, should I, or anyone else, ever need to re-order results based on a complex conditions after the results are returned.

Include your entire hook implementation. If you exclude lines of code we can’t answer the question.

Also note that the hook you implemented can only sort the current result page.

The details of the hook aren't important. It works. The correct order is achieved. The issue is that although at multiple points after the hook is invoked the order remains correct, the final display is not.

What  ViewsStyle are you using?  StylePluginBase is abstract class, maybe some child class is overriding its render() method, after calling the one from parent.

The Views style is Unformatted List, no groupings, or any other fancy stuff, like aggregation or query settings.

As chance would have it, another project presented exactly the sort of situation I posed in my question. In this case I needed to parse numerical sequences (like SemVers or IPs) out of node titles (preg_match FTW) and compare them for sorting.
I had more time to investigate and discovered both the root cause and the fix (although not in that order).

The cause: \Drupal\views\ResultRow includes the property index. views/views.theme.inc has the function template_preprocess_views_view_fields. This calls $view->style_plugin->getField() passing in said index and the field id. Herein lies the problem. Normally, without any sorting in hook_views_pre_render as I described, this index matches the key of the ResultRow in $views->result. What's happening is that even though the rows are being iterated in my desired order, the fields are being processed and displayed according to the index of that row, so the fields' display do not actually match the values for the row in question, but whichever row now has a key matching the index. Weird, huh?

The solution: In hook_views_pre_render, after completing the usort run through the array a second time (foreach or array_walk) and reset each row's index property to match its new key:
function hook_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view){
  if($view->id() === 'my_id' && $view->current_display === 'my_display') {
  /** @var \Drupal\views\ResultRow $a */
  /** @var \Drupal\views\ResultRow $b */
  usort($view->result, function($a, $b){
    // Extract values from the $a & $b rows, do a bunch of math for the final comparison of row values.
   return ($row_a_value <=> $row_b_value);
 });
 // Rows are properly sorted, but their indices don't match, so ...
 foreach($view->result as $key => &$row){
   $row->index = $key;
 }
}



